# Why is the map $A-I$ an automorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

My lecturer has mentioned that the map $A - I$ where $A$ is a non-identity orthogonal matrix is an automorphism on the set $W = \ker(A-I)^\perp$ where he said that this follows from the First Isomorphism Theorem. I see why $A-I$ maps $W$ to itself, but I don't quite see how the First Isomorphism Theorem is used to obtain isomorphism part. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: For any map, $\mathrm{im}(T)\approx X/\ker T$, and $T$ restricted to $X/\ker T$ by $T(x+\ker T):=Tx$ (well defined) is 1-1. In this case, $X=\ker(A-I)\oplus\ker(A-I)^\perp$, so $x^\perp+\ker (A-I)$ can be identified with $x^\perp\in\ker(A-I)^\perp$.

Comment: So in other words, in my case $T = A - I$?

Answer (score 1):

We should assume the orthogonality in the OP is with respect to the Hermitian inner product $(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)\mapsto\bar{\mathbf x}^T\mathbf y$ which is non-degenerate and therefore
$$\Bbb C^{(n)}=\ker(\mathbf{A-I})\oplus\ker(\mathbf{A-I})^\perp$$
where $\bar{\cdot},^{T},\perp$, respectively, denote complex conjugation, matrix transposition, orthogonal complementation and $\mathbf A$ is a complex orthogonal $n\times n$ matrix.
$$\ker(\mathbf A-\mathbf I)=\ker(\mathbf A(\mathbf I-\bar{\mathbf A}^T))=\ker(\mathbf I-\bar{\mathbf A}^T)=\ker(\bar{\mathbf A}^T-\mathbf I)$$
$$\therefore\;\;\;(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)\in\ker(\mathbf A-\mathbf I)\times\ker(\mathbf A-\mathbf I)^\perp\implies\mathbf 0=(\bar{\mathbf A}^T-\mathbf I)\mathbf x\implies\mathbf 0^T=\bar{\mathbf x}^T(\mathbf{A-I})$$
$$\therefore\;\;\;(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)\in\ker(\mathbf A-\mathbf I)\times\ker(\mathbf A-\mathbf I)^\perp\implies \bar{\mathbf x}^T(\mathbf{A-I})\mathbf y=0$$

Therefore $\Psi:\mathbf y\mapsto(\mathbf{A-I})\mathbf y$ defines a linear endomorphism of $\ker(\mathbf{A-I})^\perp$ with trivial kernel because $\ker(\mathbf{A-I})\cap\ker(\mathbf{A-I})^\perp=\{\mathbf 0\}$. Therefore $\Psi\in\text{Aut}(\ker(\mathbf{A-I} ))$.

Comment: (+1) Note that $(\bar{\mathbf A}^T-\mathbf I)\mathbf x=\bar{\mathbf x}^T(\mathbf{A-I})$ is technically not correct.

Comment: @Chrystomath. It $is$ correct. Do you remember where $\mathbf x$ came from ? Reread the answer and recall $\mathbf x\in\ker(\mathbf{A-I})=\ker(\bar{\mathbf A}^T-\mathbf I)$.

Comment: Maybe it's an issue of notation. $Bx$ is a column vector, $x^\top A$ is a row vector.

Comment: @Chrystomath. Fair enough. I replaced one case of $\mathbf 0$ with $\mathbf 0^T$.